# Investigate correlations between a big amount of binary variables and a metric variable

Tags: r, binary, correlation

I am trying to investigate a dataset with about 260 binary varibles and a metric one. These are dummies of categorial variables, which I want to regress on the metric variable.

How can I visualize them?

I first tried plot() but it wasnt possible to use it on the whole dataset and even if I use only a view I can´t interpret them.

[image]

I tried `pairs()`, but there came the output:

> 'Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large'

I also tried `sjp.corr()` from `sjPlot` package, but it is too small and wasn't interpretable.

I´m not really experienced in handeling data like this, what would you recommend me? how you analyse and interpret the data (even non graphical)? Woould you recommend not to try to interpret it graphically? I also got the problem, if I try to investigate it non graphically and use the command rcorr() of the Hmisc package. Then I only got an 3 x 260 table and it omitts 258 rows? What can I do?

I am really sorry but I cant show you the data :( But I would be glad if you could still give me some advice

Comment: Hi Guybrush, welcome to SO! If you cannot show your data, you can give us some fake data to copy and paste in our R, to try to replicate your issues.

Comment: @Guybrush what would you like to figure out about these data?

Comment: @ s_t Thank you! I am not sure if I am abled to tell you how to reproduce an representative dataset. Sorry for that.

Comment: @Salman I think this is the worst answer, but I dont know. I made an regresson with the data but with an bad R² and I got recommended to look at the correlations to get an idea how to cluster the data to improve it. Yes I know, normally you first look at the correlatons ... ;)  My real problem could be that (honestly) I dont know exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: @Guybrush did it help you?

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide us,the data, but out of your plot i can get some points

1. **You have 2 features,** which one of them is Binary (1,0), meanwhile the other one is an integer from 0 to 600.
2. The frequency of the both 0s, and 1s are more when the other feature is between 0 and 150.

So, given the above information i generate a random dataset for myself, and answer your question based on my data.

```
dt<-data.frame(binary=sample(c("0","1"),100,replace = T ),
               price=rnbinom(100, 100,0.5 )  )
```

---

In my dataset the `binary` is a string which can only contain 1 or 0. and the price is a numeric value.

The first thing i can do is to study the `price` feature, to understand its histogram, it helps me to get the distribution of it.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dt,aes( x=price, fill=binary ))+
  geom_histogram( position="identity", alpha=.5)+
  geom_density()
```

and the result is:

[image]

In the next step, i wish to compare the frequency of 1s with 0s

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dt,aes(binary,fill=binary))+
  geom_bar()
```

and it shows me the frequency of them:

[image]

---

I doubt if regression is a good choice to get a prediction. I would say, the best choice here is a classification using `rpart`

```
library(rpart)
model<-rpart(binary~price,dt, method="class"  )
```

But, don't forget to make `test`, and `train` data seperated.